# Infopath forms in standalone application

Tags: infopath

We want to use Infopath forms in stand alone application. How can we use Infopath forms in standalone application?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean without connecting to Sharepoint.  Then yes you can use it as a standalone application.

**Edit**
My assumtion was that standalone meant using infopath client by itself to create the XML datafiles.

If I understand correctly you are wanting to use Infopath Form Services to deliver web based forms.  In that scenario, no you will not be able to use it without Sharepoint as Infopath Form Services is built on top of Sharepoint 2007.

It is possible to convert an Infopath form to be viewable on the web however.  To do this you will need to be familiar with XML and XSL and only use browser compatible controls.  The Infopath XSN file is really a CAB file that contains an the View (XSL), data (XML), schema (XSD) and other files.  to make the form viewable on the web means editing the xml template to point to the XSL view rather than opening up in Infopath.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Install InfoPath designer to design client based forms and install InfoPath Viewer on client machines to work on published forms.